# Exception sending a message

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've installed ROS-Melodic (full desktop) with Gazebo 9 on 3 different PC: 2 of them are with Ubuntu 18.04 and third one with WSL Ubuntu 18.04 (Windows 10). After a fresh install I get  `Exception sending a message`, which is being printed infinitely after starting gazebo (gzserver, roslaunch):
[image: image description]

One more thing - I use gazebo via ssh or terminal (wsl), so there is no GUI.

Here is also a [related question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20028/why-i-am-getting-exception-sending-a-message-when-starting-gazebo-and-how-to-solve-it/)

**Update:**

I've noticed that the problem happens **only when I open VPN** connection. Here is the `--verbose` output on my local machine in WLS Ubuntu 18.04 (the same output is on remote PC with Ubuntu 18.04 over VPN and ssh)

```
ubuntu:~$ gzserver --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 9.0.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 127.0.0.1
Exception sending a messageException sending a message

shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
[Err] [OpenAL.cc:84] Unable to open audio device[default]
 Audio will be disabled.
Exception sending a message
Exception sending a message
Exception sending a message
...
[Wrn] [Time.cc:439] Sleep time is larger than clock resolution, skipping sleep
[Wrn] [Time.cc:439] Sleep time is larger than clock resolution, skipping sleep
[Wrn] [Time.cc:439] Sleep time is larger than clock resolution, skipping sleep
...
Exception sending a message
xception sending a message33m
Exception sending a message
...
[Wrn] [Time.cc:439] Sleep time is larger than clock resolution, skipping sleep
[Wrn] [Time.cc:439] Sleep time is larger than clock resolution, skipping sleep
Exception sending a message
Exception sending a message
Exception sending a message
.....
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21103/exception-sending-a-message/) by [aray](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7284/aray/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 76 on 2018-11-17

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2018-11-20**:
Is the above terminal output from an Ubuntun 18.04 machine? And, can you post the output of the command: gzserver --verbose?

**Comment by [aray](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7284/aray/) on 2018-11-20**:
Yes, the same output on 3 different machines with ubuntu 18.04. I've updated my question.

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2018-11-22**:
The option --verboss does not exist (gzserver will start anyway but without special output), try it with --verbose, the output will differ and give more informations on what is going on.

**Comment by [aray](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7284/aray/) on 2018-11-22**:
sorry, I've updated the question once again. anyway the output doesn't contain any useful information

**Comment by [mogumbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6355/mogumbo/) on 2019-03-20**:
I can confirm this problem. I only see the error message while I have VPN connection established.

**Comment by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) on 2019-03-20**:
Could you try setting the IGN_IP environment variable to one of the IP addresses of your machine?

**Comment by [aray](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7284/aray/) on 2019-03-30**:
export IGN_IP=127.0.0.1 solves the problem. thank you!

**Comment by [mogumbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6355/mogumbo/) on 2019-06-25**:
That solves it for me too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As Carlos Agüero  pointed out,  `IGN_IP` hast to be set to  IP addresses of your machine.

Setting the IP to the local host solved my problem:

```
export IGN_IP=127.0.0.1
```

---

Originally posted by [aray](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7284/aray/) with karma: 76 on 2019-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2